# Can you deauth a car, if so what would happen?

Tags: wifi, deauth-attack, vehicle

What would happen if someone deauthed a cars mac address?

Comment: deauth from *what*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the car has WiFi, it would behave the same as any other WiFi enabled device.

If the car has an access point, then any connected devices could be disconnected until the attack stops. If the car is connected to an access point, then it could be disconnected until the attack stops.